# Inserting number as well as text in a field in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, buffer

I am trying to buffer polygons based on the value of a attribute table, though I need it in centimeter level. There is no option to the buffer tool which uses field to set the centimeter.
Thus, I am trying to to populate the field with value, which is specific buffer distant for each polygon and text "Centimeter" in it, as with this way it seems to work to buffer polygons at centimeter level.
Can anyone share the knowledge how to put number and text in one field?

Comment: A quick workaround would be to convert your centimeter values to meters.

Comment: Yeah, that may work, but I need buffer distance which are in between a meter, such as 0.88, 0.46, 0.48 and so on, which seems not to work if I convert values to meter as buffer simply rounds the number so I will get, either 1, or 0 as a buffer distance.

Comment: You need to use floating-point columns to store real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple concatenation as both combining fields are being strings with "Field Calculator" worked out. !field name! + " " + !field name! is the running it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new text field in your feature class and then populate it with Field Calculator (right click on column header in attribute table -> Field Calculator):

```
[name_of_the_field_with_cm_values] & " Centimeter"
```

Make sure you use VB Script as parser.